# react decorator with babel

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have a standard startup app created by `create-react-app`. 
I want to avoid importing and loading hundreds of modules I don't even know what they do. 
So I started with an almost blank `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^15.4.1",
"react-dom": "^15.4.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.1",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-logger": "^2.7.4",
"redux-promise-middleware": "^4.2.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"devDependencies":
{},
```

With Redux I'm at the point where I need the `babel-plugin-transformer`. Until now I only start my app by console: `npm start`, which is executing `react-scripts start`. 
I have no Idea what react-script is doing, according to react it starts a webpack-server and compiles es6 into es5.
I went to the babel page and found a description to :

```
npm install --dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators
```

And create a `.babelrc.json` file that looks like this:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators"]
}
```

I started by `npm start` and as I expected ... nothing happened ... 
The `@connect` decorator is still not working.
I have no `webpack.json`, because this is managed by create-react-app. All I have is the `package.json`.

**My question:**

How do I setup `babel` (-transform) in the `package.json`. 
I need all the steps because all I have is the `package.json` above now including this:

```
devDependencies:{
"babel-core": "^6.21.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators": "^6.13.0",
"react-scripts": "0.8.4",
"webpack": "^1.14.0"
}
```

No Idea how to go on with this.

Comment: I'm curious about this create-react-app. I'm going to look into this to see if I can assist you

Answer (score 0):

Ok so looking around the folder structure, react-scripts is a subfolder in the node-modules folder.

All the npm scripts are in a folder named, appropriately enough, scripts and the webpack configs are in a folder named config.

I would think you could make backup copies of whatever you need to change and then alter the originals.

Comment: The webpack.config.dev.js isn't touched in the config folder. The .babelrc.json isn't touched either. I further have no idea how to link the files. It's where I wish me back to c++ or java ... *sigh.

Comment: my sincere apologies. If I find anything else, I will respond back